# "Backup in Progress" notification missing in System Tray

Tags: windows-10, backup

To My knowledge, in windows 7 when a backup was in progress using the "Backup and restore" tool, a little flag and clock notification (seen below) would appear in the system tray. This was helpful to know when a backup was in progress and you shouldn't shut down your computer or disconnect from the network if it is on a network drive.

However, using the Backup and Restore tool on windows 10, the icon does not seem to show up during a backup. Is there any way to make it come back again?

[image]

Please Note: I am not referring to the popup dialog, but the icon in the system tray to the left of the network status indicator

Comment: [Anyways make sure you have added it](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/45158-action-center-quick-actions-backup-restore-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @Ramhound pretty sure that link is talking about the action center, not just any regular old system-tray icon

Comment: It should still generate a notification though.

Comment: That's just quick actions though. Have you read my question? It looks like you just sent me to that article because it includes the word "backup", albiet under a completely different circumstance

Comment: Your screenshot is from Windows 7 not Windows 10.  Windows 10 doesn't even have that style of notifications anymore.  I DID read your question.  BE NICE.

Comment: the screenshot is in reference to how things used to be in windows 7. The specific icon I'm talking about is the one in the system tray which does still exist in windows 10. I probably should have been a bit more clear in that regard.

Comment: I understand.  But I asked are you sure your not getting notifications, in the action center, that perhaps are just not being displayed?  But as I expected, and actually originally commented, the feature is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, fortunately, no way.

In Windows 10, the component known as *Security and Maintenance* (formerly known as *Action Center* in Windows 7) no longer registers an icon with Windows taskbar. Furthermore, Backup and Restore is now a deprecated feature. Security and Maintenance operation is now completely behind the scene. It still generates toast notifications though.

Comment: That's a shame... Expected as much i suppose. No idea why they deprecated it though, it works so much better than file history